# How will achive content show more and show less in angular 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

We have 6 content div. And also we using character limit each div.
We used bootstrap 4 angular 6 version.

[6 div some toggle div content opened and some closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS04r.jpg)
How to achive this case.

Comment: There is nothing related to Angular, you can search for simple javascript hack for the same. just for ref. you can have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more

Comment: NOT. Use "Angular style", not "javascript style".  @Amil, has you try anything?

Comment: Thanks! But we using angular 6.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very easy to implement with some custom css. Give this a try:

Template:

```
<div class="container" [class.show]="show">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<button (click)="show = !show">{{ show ? 'Show less': 'Show More' }}</button>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
}
```

Component:

```
show = false;
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: hi, i have more than one paragraphs with the view more/less button but when i click on any one of them, all the paragraphs will be in view more/less mode. how do i fix this?

Comment: @mhfour, I've updated my sample StackBlitz to incorporate that behavior. Please do have a look.

Comment: this is working fine but If you have content less then 2 lines?
show more button is still visible.

Comment: Well. It can't cover n different use cases.  And one can't foresee all of them. ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<ng-container>` which not create any additional html-nodes

```
<div class="container" [class.show]="show">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Curabitur a felis odio. Nam et feugiat purus. 
  Nunc non ex mi. Phasellus at arcu id tortor gravida pellentesque. 

  <ng-container *ngIf="showMore1">

  Duis enim justo, placerat non dui non, placerat semper est. 
  Ut pulvinar aliquet lectus vulputate rutrum. 
  Maecenas suscipit, sapien ut fermentum hendrerit, 
  nibh augue scelerisque felis, in fermentum elit augue sed odio. 
  ...

  </ng-container>
</div>

<button (click)="showMore1= !showMore1">show {{showMore1 ?'less':'more' }}</button>
```